# Can I ask a question here that I already asked on another Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, migration

I have asked [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/27369/14626) on [Aviation SE](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/), which I think would also interest the community here on Engineering SE. Up to this point I haven't received complete answers to my question on Aviation.

May I post the question here on Engineering as well? It could be useful to the other readers and members to go into more depth on the question.

Answer (score 5):

So there are a couple of options to consider.

The first is ***migrating*** the question from Aviation to Engineering.  As your question has already been favorably received on Aviation and attracted a reasonable answer, it's pretty unlikely that the Aviation moderators would agree to migrate your question.

The second is ***re-posting*** your question as-is from Aviation here on Engineering.  This is also called *cross-posting* a question.  For a number of reasons, [SE strongly discourages cross-posting.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/254929)  So please don't just re-post your question.

The third option is to ***ask a new question***, and is likely the option you want.  This is where you take the existing Aviation question and re-work it so that it's directly applicable to the site you want to ask it on.  Asking a new question can use another question as supporting information, but the new question ought to be easily discernible from the existing one.

You didn't say what you have a question about regarding the original question you asked on Aviation.  Based upon the comments there, I suspect your new question is related to the ratio of $\frac{C_D}{C_L}$ and how that relates to the rest of the equation(s).  To be honest, that sounds like something that could be clarified within the existing Aviation question and not worth opening a brand new question about.

On the other hand, if you have a broader question that was sparked by the answer to your Aviation question ***and*** you're wanting to understand the engineering behind that question, that would be a valid question to ask here.

And as a final point of SE netiquette, I would encourage you to edit your comments on Aviation into your existing question and then remove those now obsolete comments.  You don't need to say "EDIT" or any other meta-blather in your question.  SE provides a revision history so anyone who is curious can see how a question evolved.

Comment: I agree - looking at the question on Aviation, it is very well received and has attracted a high-quality answer, so there is no need to migrate. And we should not scatter the solutions to any problem across multiple sites; that only makes it less likely that any one reader will be able to see all the answers and compare them on the same basis. Making the existing question the best it can be, and perhaps attracting additional answers with a bounty or by advertising in [chat], is the way to go.

Comment: @Air thanks for the edit with the MSE reference.